# SVG animation with SMIL

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, smil

I have some questions about working with smil SVG animations and changing stuff with javascript/jquery otf.

Here is what I already tried:

**HTML/XML:**

```
        <svg version="1.1" id="story_animation_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
        viewBox="0 0 400 500" enable-background="new 0 0 400 500" xml:space="preserve" style="background-color:#4B4542;">

            <g id="story_1">
                <path id="story_1_1" style="fill:none; stroke:#fff; stroke-width:2;" d="M200,100z">
                    <animate id="story_1_1_1"
                             attributeName="d" 
                             from="M200,100l0,0" to="M200,100l0,380" dur="1s"
                             begin="0s;story_1_1_2.end"
                             end=""
                    />
                    <animate id="story_1_1_2" 
                             attributeName="d" 
                             from="M200,100l0,380" to="M200,100l0,0" dur="1s"
                             begin="story_1_1_1.end"
                             end=""
                    />
                </path>
                <path id="story_1_2" style="fill:none; stroke:#fff; stroke-width:2;" d="M200,500z">
                    <animate id="story_1_2_1" 
                             attributeName="d" 
                             from="M200,500l0,0" to="M200,500l0,-380" dur="1s"
                             begin="story_1_1_1.begin+1s;story_1_2_2.end"
                             end=""
                    />
                    <animate id="story_1_2_2" 
                             attributeName="d" 
                             from="M200,500l0,-380" to="M200,500l0,0" dur="1s"
                             begin="story_1_2_1.end"
                             end=""
                    />
                </path>
            <g/>

            <g id="story_2">
                <path id="story_2_1" style="fill:none; stroke:#fff; stroke-width:2; stroke-dasharray:795.8291015625,795.8291015625; stroke-dashoffset:795.8291015625;" d="M200,100l86,50l-172,100l172,100l-172,100l86,50">
                    <animate id="story_2_1_1" 
                             attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" 
                             from="795.8291015625" to="-795.8291015625" dur="2s"
                             begin=""
                             calcMode="spline"
                             keySplines=".28 .25 .265 .25"
                             keyTimes="0;1"
                             end=""
                    />
                    <animate id="story_2_1_2" 
                             attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" 
                             from="795.8291015625" to="0" dur="1s"
                             begin=""
                             calcMode="spline"
                             keySplines=".28 .25 .265 .25"
                             keyTimes="0;1"
                             end=""
                    />
                </path>
            <g/>

        </svg>
```

**JS/jQuery:**

on in this case key press event do the following:

```
document.getElementById( 'story_1_1_1' ).attributes[ 5 ].value = '';

document.getElementById( 'story_1_1_1' ).attributes[ 6 ].value ='story_1_1_1.end';

document.getElementById( 'story_1_2_1' ).attributes[ 6 ].value ='story_1_2_1.end';

document.getElementById( 'story_2_1_1' ).attributes[ 5 ].value= 'story_1_1_2.end;story_2_1_1.end';
```

**Admired Result:**

I'd like to achieve:

- having an animation loop running constantly animating
- on event trigger (e.g. click, keypress, ...) end the current running animation at the end of the current iteration
- on end of first animation start the second one
  (- repeat for more animations)
  (- ideally doing the same thing reverse: going from animation 2 to 1)

**Actual Result:**

What happens so far:

- animation 1 loop works fine
- on key press:
- case 1 (you pressed while the top line is going down):

  - It works
- case 2 (you pressed while the top line is going up):

  - still animation one iteration more and then stops

I'm open for different approaches and/or ideas of how to do that. SMIL seemed at least at the beginning a quick and easy way also also performance-wise on mobile it works great. Perhaps css3 animation is better in this case?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard one...I messed around with it here:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {//spacebar trigger
    if (e.keyCode === 0 || e.keyCode === 32) {
        $('#story_1_1_1, #story_1_1_2, #story_1_2_1, #story_1_2_2').attr('end', 'story_2_1_1.begin');
        $('#story_2_1_1').attr('begin', '0s;story_2_1_2.end');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kt7gax2a/2/